# easy way to detect infinite loop in kernel of the linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I've just spent my 2 extra hours trying to find bug in my modification of the kernel of the linux, every time when I was connecting module to the kernel it was good but when I unconnected it my mouse stopped to work, so using printk I found infinite loop, my question is does somebody know nice techniques to detect such bugs, sometimes it is difficult to find such loops, and linux becomes unpredictable, `so how can I avoid infinite loops` in kernel thanks in advance

Comment: Google "The Halting Problem".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some infrastructure in the kernel that allows you to detect some lockup conditions :

[CONFIG_DETECT_SOFTLOCKUP](http://kernel.xc.net/html/linux-2.6.31/alpha/DETECT_SOFTLOCKUP)

[CONFIG_DETECT_HUNG_TASK](http://kernel.xc.net/html/linux-2.6.31/alpha/DETECT_HUNG_TASK)

And the various lock checking function you can find in the "[Kernel Hacking](http://kernel.xc.net/html/linux-2.6.31/alpha/#Kernel_hacking)" section of the kernel config

Answer (score 0):

I've always found printk useful for that, as you did.

Other options would be running your kernel in Bochs in debugging mode. And as I recall, there's a way of running the kernel in gdb. Google can help with those options.

---

Oh, you said "avoid" not "debug"... hmm, the best way to avoid is *do not hack the kernel* :^)

Seriously, when doing kernel-level programming you have to be extra careful. Add a main() to the code that stress-tests your routines in usermode before adding to the running kernel. And read over your code, especially after you've isolated the bug to a particular section. I once found an infinite loop in LynxOS's terminal driver when some ANSI art hung the operating system. Some junior programmer, apparently, had written that part, parsing the escape sequence options as text rather than numbers. The code was so bad, I got disgusted trying to locate the exact error that forced the loop, and just rewrote most of the driver. And tested it in usermode before adding to the kernel.

Comment: Watchdogs are useful for avoiding infinite loops, that is, until you try to set a harware watchdog to 1 minute, and the BIOS, on warm reboots, first sets the unit to seconds and then...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enable [the NMI watchdog](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/nmi_watchdog.txt).