# How does the Kernel detects Java infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops, operating-system, kernel, infinite-loop

In Operating system class, I was asked how does the kernel (OS) know if an
application like JAVA is in an infinite (while) loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365898/easy-way-to-detect-infinite-loop-in-kernel-of-the-linux

Answer (score 2):

In most operating systems, the OS kernel has no idea and does not care if an application is in an infinite loop.